# autoreply program sendmail giving "DSN: Service unavailable" error

Tags: perl, sendmail

I am trying to use an auto reply program for one of the users.

It works fine when I have user email address defined in `.forward` file but it gives following error when I put it in script:

```
Jun 28 12:25:38 localhost sendmail[5210]: s5SJPFkN005208: to="|/home/alpha/autoreply.pl", ctladdr=alpha@localhost (501/501), delay=00:00:10, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=prog, pri=60446, dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Jun 28 12:25:38 localhost sendmail[5210]: s5SJPFkN005208: s5SJPckN005210: DSN: Service unavailable
```

Do I have have make any changes in sendmail configs (i.e. symbolic link etc)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was /etc/smrsh did not have symbolic link for perl which can be defined as

ln -s /usr/bin/perl /etc/smrsh/perl

Answer (score 0):

1.Have you checked problems mentioned in sendmail FAQ?
[Sendmail-FAQ-3.11: Why can't my users forward their mail to a program?](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/faq_ver_8_issues/#3.11)
2. On most linuxes sendmail uses procmail as local mailer program.
You may try to execute your script from `~/.procmailrc` of the user.